# Visual Studio 2013 crashing when opening debug tab

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, xamarin, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

Visual Studio 2013 Professional crashes when I try to open the Debug tab in the properties panel of a Windows Phone 8 project. No error given only "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 has stopped working". Attached Visual Studio as a debugger and got the following error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.ProjectSystem.Base.dll

I'm running Visual Studio as an Administrator

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: How can I fix this error?

Comment: You should first try reinstalling Visual Studio/Windows Phone 8 SDK, as the error seems to be very general.

Comment: Still don't know what the problem is but I do know that Xamarin for Visual Studio is the problem. When I uninstall Xamarin all works fine. After I installing Xamarin the problem is back.
Xamarin.Android version 4.10.01073
Xamarin Studio 4.2.1
Xamarin.iOS 1.8.365.0

Comment: The best way is to go to Xamarin and report it, http://xamarin.com/support

Comment: I did but Xamarin support is awful, so I expect no solution from them. Also posted the problem on the Xamarin Forum.

Comment: Got a temporary fix by following a bug report on bugzilla.xamarin.com (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=16434). Before opening the solution first remove the suo file. It's a hidden file stored with the solution.

Comment: Thanks, it was driving me crazy!

Comment: I feel kinda compelled to comment that Xamarin support is anything but awful. It will *probably* be awful if you give them little information to begin with, but in my experience, Xamarin support has been excellent.

Comment: @Lasse When I originally posted this problem I didn't know Xamarin was the problem, that's why I hadn't given that much information concerning Xamarin. After I did know, a day later, I send it to Xamarin and included version info etc. I also added a comment here. What extra information would you like to see? The fact, for me, is that Xamarin support sends back halve backed answers that don't solve problems. I've experienced this several times, hence my comment. The bugzilla site however is very good and they provide help that leads to solutions. Mailing Xamarin never solved anything for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with a very weird behavior. The first time I create a WP8 project in VS2013 I have all the options for emulators, the designer, the devices and even the debug tab of the project  working fine. All the markup of the mainpage.xaml is ok. If I close and reopen a new instance of the project in visual studio 2013, everything start having problems: I can not open the debug tab, the emulators optios are gone, the device windows appear in read only mode, The markup of the xaml says an "Invalid Markup" and got errors like:

The name "PhoneApplicationPage" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone".

BUT: It compiles and run in the emulator.

I also DO have all the Xamarin tools installed. It seems I am not getting this errors in Visual Studio 2012.

SOLUTION: From Xamarin Studio check for update and install the android SDK 4.10.2 and GTK# (2.12.0.0). At the time of this writing you have to subscribe to the BETA Channel to get this update. After installation you DONT have to delete de .suo file of the project and everything looks fine again in Visual Studio 2013