# VS 2012 not starting

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, git-extensions

I tried to start my Visual Studio 2012 Professional as every day.
Out of nothing, it will not start anymore.

Already googled around but can't find a solution that realy solves my problem.
If possible I would like not reinstallin Visual Studio completely.

Some facts I already figured out:

1. I did not install any new packages/updates since yesterday
2. It starts with devenv.exe /SafeMode
3. It does not start with devenv.exe /ResetSettings
4. Starting with devenv.exe /Log will fail, but it shows the following:

   > Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.ProjectSystem.Base.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   >         C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW......\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.ProjectSystem.Base.dll

The file mentioned is locally not existing. At my colleagues computer this file also not exists but Visual Studio is running normally.

I'm currently running sfc /scannnow in case any system-files are somehow corrupted. (Nothing found)

Any ideas what I can do next to find the issue?

Plugins/Extensions installed:

- ReSharper 7
- GitExtensions

**Update**:

Repairing ReSharper through Programs and Features seems to fix the problem. After restarting same error occurs

Comment: Do you have Xamarin tools installed? If so you may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337032/visual-studio-2013-crashing-when-opening-debug-tab

Comment: Have you tried repairing Visual studio from programs and features? And have you tried clearing the meta-data cache http://stackoverflow.com/a/20301710/736079?

Comment: The `Microsoft.VisualStudio.SmartDevice.ProjectSystem.Base.dll` is part of the Windows Phone tools which may need to be repaired.

Comment: Re-Install of ReSharper fixed the problem at first. After my computer was in Hibernate-Mode, Visual Studio again did not start. Any ideas?